# HTML, CSS, Не работает hover

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Всем привет, не работает анимация при навидение на иконку, что я не правильно делаю почему не работает?
Пример кода взял отсюда [Social Icons vision 3D](https://codepen.io/miguelcast/pen/pwZMOJ)[image: DevTools][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.footer-social a>img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #transparent;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 48px;
    height: 59px;
    -webkit-animation: icon3d 200ms 10;
     animation: icon3d 200ms 10;
    color: #fff;
}


.footer-social a:hover img {
 -webkit-animation: icon3d 200ms infinite;
 animation: icon3d 200ms infinite;
}

@keyframes icon3d {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 5px 4px var(--redColor), -5px -6px var(--blueColor);
  }
  25% {
    text-shadow: -5px -6px var(--redColor), 5px 4px var(--blueColor);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 5px -4px var(--redColor), -8px 4px var(--blueColor);
  }
  75% {
    text-shadow: -8px -4px var(--redColor), -5px -4px var(--blueColor);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: -5px 0 var(--redColor), 5px -4px var(--blueColor);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-social default-container">
            <p>Follow us via social media:</p>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/img/icons/youtube.svg"   alt="social">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/img/icons/facebook.svg"  alt="social">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/img/icons/instagram.svg"  alt="social">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/img/icons/twitter.svg"   alt="social">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/img/icons/telegram.svg"  alt="social">
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: А на каком тексте ты ожидаешь отображения анимации тени?

Comment: Не на тексте, а при наведение на картинку должна происходить анимаия тени и я не вижу приминения пседо :hover в DevTools может я не правельно указала hover

Comment: text-shadow это тень текста может тебе нужен box-shadow

Comment: спасибо помогло правда не то что мне казалось получилось
Получаеться что он вокруг иконки применяется эффект тени даже если задать inset то тут смысла нету. Там по ссылке пример то что я  скинул там получаеться как будто тень копирует иконку и она не много отриваеться, а у меня получаеться что просто тень вокруг иконки разноцветный квадрат можно сказать

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `text-shadow` применяется только к тексту, потому иконки должны быть символьными, то есть быть частью шрифта. У Вас же это изображения, а не шрифт.

Более универсальный способ реализации - использование [CSS-фильтров](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter). В данном случае - `drop-shadow()`, так как он влияет и на текст и на прозрачные изображения. (Фильтр `invert()` здесь из-за того, что на скорую руку не нашёл белых иконок).

```css
.footer-social a>img {
  --redColor: red;
  --blueColor: blue;
}

.footer-social a>img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0 16px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  animation: icon3d 200ms 10;
}

.footer-social a:hover img {
  animation: icon3d 200ms infinite;
}

@keyframes icon3d {
  0% { filter: invert(100%) drop-shadow(5px 4px var(--redColor)) drop-shadow(-5px -6px var(--blueColor)); }
  25% { filter: invert(100%) drop-shadow(-5px -6px var(--redColor)) drop-shadow(5px 4px var(--blueColor)); }
  50% { filter: invert(100%) drop-shadow(5px -4px var(--redColor)) drop-shadow(-8px 4px var(--blueColor)); }
  75% { filter: invert(100%) drop-shadow(-8px -4px var(--redColor)) drop-shadow(-5px -4px var(--blueColor)); }
  100% { filter: invert(100%) drop-shadow(-5px 0 var(--redColor)) drop-shadow(5px -4px var(--blueColor)); }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-social default-container">
  <p>Follow us via social media:</p>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/glyph-neue/2x/youtube-play.png" alt="social"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/2x/facebook-f--v2.png" alt="social"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/glyph-neue/2x/instagram-new.png" alt="social"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/2x/twitter.png" alt="social"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/2x/telegram-app.png" alt="social"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you не знал что с тенями можно так анимацию делать, буду дальше учиться